# How to change a column name in multiple files?

Tags: text-processing

I am wanting to change the name of column number 5 in each file to the file name itself for all files in a given directory. I have 250 files in the directory and the column names are tab-delimited.

At the moment, all files have identical column names.
Example of file `met-d-Glucose.txt`:

```
                FID  IID  PHENO    CNT SCORESUM
  3999347013_R01C01    1     -9     21 -0.217178
  3999347013_R01C02    1     -9     21 -0.054835
  3999347013_R02C01    1     -9     21 -0.130287
  3999347013_R02C02    1     -9     21 0.0062288
  3999347013_R03C01    1     -9     21 -0.0933029
  3999347013_R03C02    1     -9     21 0.0434727
```

I want to change the name of column 5 to the file name. e.g. the output for the example file named `met-d-Glucose.txt` above would be:

```
                FID  IID  PHENO    CNT met-d-Glucose.txt
  3999347013_R01C01    1     -9     21 -0.217178
  3999347013_R01C02    1     -9     21 -0.054835
  3999347013_R02C01    1     -9     21 -0.130287
  3999347013_R02C02    1     -9     21 0.0062288
  3999347013_R03C01    1     -9     21 -0.0933029
  3999347013_R03C02    1     -9     21 0.0434727
```

The original column name is always SCORESUM.
The header line is always the first line.
There are never columns after the 5th column.
SCORESUM does not appear anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are replacing a single, fixed string without inadverted duplicates, the following shell loop invoking (GNU) `sed` would work:

```bash
for f in *.txt; do sed -i '1s/SCORESUM/'"$f"'/' "$f"; done
```

This will iterate over all files matching the wildcard pattern `*.txt` (adjust if more specificity is needed) and apply use `sed` to substitute (`s`) the pattern `SCORESUM` with the filename, stored in the shell variable `"$f"`, but only in the first line of the file (the leading `1`). It uses the `-i` option of GNU `sed` to edit the files in-place. If that option is not available in your `sed` implementation, you will need to work with a temporary file:

```bash
for f in *.txt; do sed '1s/SCORESUM/'"$f"'/' "$f" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt "$f"; done
```

Note that in order to make use of the shell variable, the single-quoted `sed` program `'1s/.../.../'` is interrupted and a double-quoted shell variable reference interjected.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of GNU Sed it is easier to do it in two separate commands.
The first one is to write down its name in the second line to each file:

```
sed -i 2F *
```

The second - edit:

```
sed -i '1!b;N;s/\S*\n//' *
```

The fact is that `-i` flag delimits the addressing of lines by files (similar to the FNR variable in AWK)